# React error al traer valores con props

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

La siguiente funcion recibe **userName, firstName y lastName** mediante props, el cual renderiza correctamente dentro del **return** pero no funciona en la variable que se encuentra antes.

En estas lineas da error:

```
{
      id: 4,
      userName: { props.userName },
      firstName: { props.firstName },
      lastName: { props.lastName },
    },
```

Pero no da error en estas:

```
<tr>
              <td>{props.userName}</td> <td>{props.firstName}</td>{" "}
              <td>{props.lastName}</td>
            </tr>
```

El código completo es el siguiente:

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "../App.css";

export function UsersFunction(props) {
  const [getUser, setUser] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      userName: "scostilla",
      firstName: "Sebastian",
      lastName: "Costilla",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      userName: "javicost",
      firstName: "Javier",
      lastName: "Costilla Capobianco",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      userName: "paulicost",
      firstName: "Paula",
      lastName: "Costilla Capobianco",
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      userName: { props.userName },
      firstName: { props.firstName },
      lastName: { props.lastName },
    },
  ]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>
        <h1>LISTADO DE USUARIOS</h1>
        <table className="table">
          <tr>
            <th>Nombre de Usuario</th> <th>Nombre</th> <th>Apellido</th>
          </tr>
          {getUser.map((user) => (
            <tr key={user.id}>
              <td>{user.userName}</td> <td>{user.firstName}</td>{" "}
              <td>{user.lastName}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
          <tr>
              <td>{props.userName}</td> <td>{props.firstName}</td>{" "}
              <td>{props.lastName}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

El valor del props llega de la siguiente manera:

```
    <Router>
<input
          type="text"
          value={getLastName}
          onChange={(e) => setLastName(e.target.value)}
          placeholder="Apellido"
        />
        <p />

        <Routes>
          <Route path="/RollTheDice" element={<RollTheDice />} />
          <Route path="/Welcome" element={<Welcome name={getName} />} />
          <Route path="/UsersComponent" element={<UsersComponent />} />
          <Route path="/UsersFunction" element={<UsersFunction userName={getUserName} firstName={getFirstName} lastName={getLastName} />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
```

Comment: los `props` los tenes que enviar encerrando el valor en comillas, por ejemplo `userName="juan"`

Comment: los traigo desde una vble, que la ingreso desde un input, al verlo por consola, y en la parte del return (dentro de la tabla) si me muestr bien los datos, solo en la funcion no puedo obtenerlos

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontré la respuesta, el error es porque encierro las props entre llaves, se soluciona de la siguiente manera:

```
{
  id: 4,
  userName:  props.userName,
  firstName:  props.firstName,
  lastName:  props.lastName,
},
```